# Guzzle's client does not returns error message. Only "result" is returned

Tags: php, guzzle

I don't know why Guzzle's client only returns "result" value. How can I get whole response data.

(1) method_A returns result. Guzzle's client returns the result. This is no problem.

```
// HTTP request with curl

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"method_A","params":["xxx"],"id":1}' https://example.com/rpc
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x5209"}

// HTTP request with Guzzle

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com/rpc']);
$response = $client->request('POST', '', ['json' => $params]);
echo json_encode($response) // 0x5209
```

(2) method_B returns error. Guzzle's client returns empty instead of the error. This is my issue.

```
// HTTP request with curl

curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"method_B","params":["xxx"],"id":1}' https://example.com/rpc
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"nonce too low"}}

// HTTP request with Guzzle

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://example.com/rpc']);
$response = $client->request('POST', '', ['json' => $params]);
echo json_encode($response) // empty
```

FYI. https://example.com/rpc returns always 200 responses even the response data has errors for some reasons.

---

Update 1

I tried like followings.

```
Log::info($response);
Object of class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response could not be converted to string

Log::info(json_decode($response));
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Log::info(var_dump($response));
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>object</b>(<i>GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response</i>)[<i>374</i>]
  <i>private</i> 'reasonPhrase' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'OK'</font> <i>(length=2)</i>

...
```

Comment: 1) Shouldn't it be `json_decode()`? 2) Did you check the raw response? Try `var_dump($response);` and `echo $response;`

Comment: @ishegg Thanks for your comment. I tried it but still I can not get the error.